# How to determine color hierarchy using images library in python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to determine the color hierarchy of some lines in an image, using the images library in python.

If you are not familiar with the images library, it represents an image as a list of lists (a matrix). Each item inside the inner list is a tuple with RGB values (e.g. (255, 255, 255)).

How would this be possible? The background color is known, the lines are always straight and in different colors.

A sample image can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEyJZ.jpg

The answer for this image would be: white first, red second, green third and then the background color (gray) last.
The colors would be represented in tuples of RGB values of course

Comment: Which *images* library do you mean? Please click [edit] and add your latest/greatest code. Thank you.

Comment: Is your sample image actually representative? Are your lines really always straight? Or sometimes twisting?Always vertical/horizontal? Or sometimes diagonal? Always the same 3 colours? Or sometimes more?

Comment: It's a custom library but the only purpose of the library is to take images and make them into matrices and save matrices as png files.

Comment: Lines are always straight, always in a + shape, number of colors changes

Comment: What do you mean *"custom library"*? Where is it please?

Comment: It's given, i dont know any further information about the library

Answer (score 0):

As you have been unable to provide any information or references to this mystery *"images"* library, I am suggesting a different approach.

If your images are always in a plus shape, i.e. axis-aligned and symmetrical, you can probably use a simple heuristic to find the layer ordering.

- the image is symmetrical, so you only need to process the rows or the columns but not both
- the grey pixels are a distraction, make them black (i.e. zero) so they contribute nothing
- sum across the rows with `np.sum(..., axis=1)` so you find the horizontal lines, i.e. where the row sums to a large number
- look at each line you find, and test the number of unique colours in it - if it is 1 (i.e. white in your diagram) it is top-most. If it is 2, it is the next layer down and so on.